# Detect sound on phone

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have the radio app. Almost good work, but I want to pause my radio, when user turn on another sound on her phone(youtube, insta). How can I detect another sound, that pause my exoplayer and start, when another ended ? Sorry, for my English

Answer (score 1):

In AudioManager class there is a  `isMusicActive()` function which detects if music is playing. Maybe that'll solve you problem. Try it and do let me know if it helps.

Also check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive())